# Do you need a server to develop an app for Google Home?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

Is an application server required in order to develop programs for Google Home devices, or can development be done in a way that does not require me to host my own code?

Answer (score 2):

OAuth2.0 is only needed if the Google Home device/user needs to be linked to an external account. (For example if you need complicated setup and load that off to an own Android App or if you need to access third party services that require authorization on behalf of the Google Home user and impersonating as that user)

An action that runs only on the device and built with Dialogflow or the Actions SDK can be deployed on Google's Firebase Cloud without the need for any own services.

Comment: "Runs on the device" is not exactly accurate. All Actions run on a server. It can be a Firebase server, but it is still a server.

Comment: Yeah, probably wrong wording. What I mean is an action where the user only interacts with the device itself and no external services like in the examples mentioned.

Comment: It's worth noting that you can build many simple conversational Actions within Dialogflow, without writing a single line of code. You can also create a trivia game, personality quiz or flash card game using the Actions Templates feature: https://developers.google.com/actions/templates/first-app